# SqlCommand read one value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlcommand

I have a problem with the value returned from `SqlCommand`, I have this code:

```
string sqlSelect = "Select TOP 1 Quotation.SentToSupp as SentToSupp FROM Quotation JOIN Notifications ON Quotation.QuotationId = QuotationID ";

SqlCommand Comm = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, this.Connection);
```

`sqlSelect` query selects the first `DateTime` value. When I call to `SqlCommand` I want to get this value (just one value). I add the query and my connection fine.

But I don't know how to get my `DateTime` value... Must to use something like `ExecuteReader`?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Take a look @ `ExecuteScalar` ; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar method - *Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.*

Answer (score 9):

`ExecuteReader` works but more objects and more code are required - (An `SqlDataReader`, call to Read and Extract value). Instead you could simply use the [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) method of the `SqlCommand` object (It returns just the first column of the first row of the resultset)

```
string sqlSelect = "Select TOP 1 Quotation.SentToSupp as SentToSupp FROM ....";
SqlCommand Comm = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, this.Connection);
object result = Comm.ExecuteScalar();
if(result != null)
   DateTime dtResult = Convert.ToDateTime(result);
```

Just pay attention to the fact that `ExecuteScalar` could return a `null` value. For example, if there is a WHERE condition that excludes every row from the result returned.